# Laravel Queue How to get data in job handle method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a sequence of messsages to be sent in text messages through twilio.

I have created a controller to put the messages in a queue with the data received in the post request. Here is my controller to  make queue:

```
public function make_queue(Request $request)
{
    $data = array (
       'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
       'message'=> $request->input('message'),
       'token'=> $request->input('token')',
       'sid'=> $request->input('sid')
       );

    ProcessMessages::dispatch($data)
      ->delay(now()->addSeconds(15));

    return 'message will be sent';
}
```

And in handle the job , in the handle function

```
public function handle()
{
   $token = should_come_from job;
   $sid = should_come_from job;
   $ids = should_come_from job;
   $msg = should_come_from job;
   try{
       // send message
   }
   catch (exception $e)
   {
       handle exception
   }
```

}

I am not able to figure out how do I get the values in the handle function to actually send the message....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a constructor method in your job handler class (`ProcessMessages`), for example:

```
// namespace and use statements...

class ProcessMessages implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $token = $this->data['token'];
        // ...
    }
}
```

> Once you have written your job class, you may dispatch it using the
>   dispatch method on the job itself. The arguments passed to the
>   dispatch method will be given to the job's constructor. [Read about dispatching Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs).

Comment: now it says. ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Jobs\ProcessMessages::$data in \app\Jobs\ProcessMessages.php